# Is there a thumbnail generator plugin for video assets?

Tags: assets, plugins

I need a thumbnail image of a video which i upload as an asset. Instead of uploading an image manually I'd prefer craft to generate a thumbnail for me.

Is there a plugin I didn't find or did someone find another workaround?

Comment: Are you hosting the videos or is YouTube/Vimeo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of or can find, Marco.

It'd be interesting to see if anyone else knows of one. I guess one challenge would be to define which frame of the video should be used as a thumbnail.

I typically use YouTube or Vimeo for client videos - as you know, the 'cover images' are available for use, from both.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788287/how-to-get-hq-youtube-thumbnails

That said, often times, the client prefers to upload an image as they have more control and better quality images.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Matt, I can sure use your tipp for another project since I didn't know how to get a hq thumbnail from youtube.

In my case embedding youtube or vimeo videos isn't an option since the videos need to be self-hosted. The client won't be able to connect to the internet, only to the server craft will be running on.

Comment: I also like having control over a thumbnail but it would be nice to have a generated fallback image.

This might be an idea for a plugin if the community sees the use for it.

Good day sir.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin called 'Transcoder' But it's not free:
https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-transcoder/blob/v1/README.md